# What are the differences between "constrain" and "cause"

Tags: meaning, difference

A constrains B

A causes B

What are the differences?

Examples would be very helpful.

Comment: Welcome to ELL! -- The two verbs *constrain* and *cause* don't share a similar meaning that I can think of. Could you tell us more why do you think they're the same or related? Have you found one of them used unexpectedly in some book?

Answer (score 2):

To the extent that the meanings of these words overlap, it would be as follows.

When *A* **constrains** *B*, *A* determines *B's* shape or properties. *A* places some limits on *B*.

When *A* **causes** *B*, *A* produces *B*.

*A* can affect *B* without causing *B*.  But when *A* causes *B*, *A* also affects *B*.